# How to set proper path when rendering file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rendering

I have such problem : I want to render html file, but I'm failing to set path to my file.

I need to say, that I'm runnung Rails on Windows.

In my view I have code :

```
<%= render :file => '1509/1509/app/views/static_pages/index.html', :layout => false %>
```

but this gives me error:

```
undefined method `virtual_path' for false:FalseClass
```

My file lies here:

```
     C:\1509\1509\app\views\static_pages
```

Also tried:

```
 <%= render :file => '/views/static_pages/index.html', :layout => false %>
```

But this gives me:

```
  Missing template /views/static_pages/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "c:/1509/1509/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/views"
  * "c:/1509/1509"
  * "c:/"
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: you are doing wrong slashes as i see, try `\ ` instead of `/`.

Comment: Try with the absolute path: `render :file => 'C:/1509/1509/app/views/static_pages/index.html'`.

Comment: First suggestion gives me error #2 and secode - error #1 in my question.

Comment: Try removing the layout option. According to [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) the file is rendered without using the current layout, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute path would be:

```
<%= render :file => 'c:/1509/1509/app/views/static_pages/index.html' %>
```

Relative path:

```
<%= render :file => 'static_pages/index.html' %>
```

Comment: One more, when I'm add layout false `<%= render :file => 'static_pages/index.html' , :layout => false %>` get error : `undefined method virtual_path for false:FalseClass`

Comment: @MID This option is used inside controllers to override default layout. Templates in views are rendered without layout. So, simply don't use this option.

Comment: It continues to use layout( I mean it showing with header, footer and inside container.

Comment: @MID The code I showed was tested. It definitelly DOESN'T include anyting except the content of index.html file. The only layout that appears is the layout of applicationl. If you want to rid of it also, use: `render :layout => false` in your **action** that is responsible for showing template `<%= render :file .... %>`.

Comment: I added, what you said in controller, but stil get - http://i.imgur.com/8XDdq.jpg

Comment: @MID By looking at the image it's hard to tell what was shown that you didn't want to be. There's no magic: if you say in your **controller** `render :layout => false` then no layout will be applied on rendering of the respective action. If you are in a **template**, all `render ...` calls assume you're trying to render some partial (which naturally don't need any surrounding layout). Try looking at your log file. All rendering of your templates have to be listed there. Maybe that's how you eventually find out what's wrong. As the last resort, you can always debug your app. Good luck on that.

Comment: I know I am reviving an old thread but I am just going to throw this here. `render :layout => nil` should work, `render :layout => false` will throw `undefined method 'virtual_path'`